# Does anybody know what this Apevia X-Cruiser front panel 2 pin connector is for?

Tags: computer-building, case, front-panel

[image: front panel taken apart (front)]
This 2 pin connector is coming from the front panel of my computer case. I have no idea what it does or where it's supposed to go.

EDIT 1: More Information and Pictures

[image: front panel taken apart (back)]
 1. Here are the traced mysterious wires that go from the front panel into the case. 2. These seem to go to LED's 3. These go to LED's too
[image: front panel taken apart (front)]
Here's an LED from the partially dissected front of the front panel.
Now my question is where to plug the wires from the first picture. I don't see anything on the PSU or the motherboard.

EDIT 2: Link to Installation Manual

[Here is the PDF installation manual link.](http://www.apevia.com/umanual/um-x-cruiser.pdf)

On step 30, it states:

> Install LED Lights: Find 2* LED connectors from the front to a 4-pin connector Female from the front
>   Panel. They are 2*2-pin connectors that lead out to 2*4-pin connector (1*Male, 1*Female)

I see the two 2-pin connectors (see first picture above). But I don't know what the instructions mean describing that they "lead out to 2*4pin connector (1*Male, 1*Female)" That part isn't even grammatically correct, along with being confusing in the first place.

Does anybody know what that is supposed to mean?

Comment: Your picture doesn't show us where the cable comes from.

Comment: Looks like a connector for a fan.  Is there a fan in the case that doesn't spin, that is on the end of those wires?

Comment: @david schwartz I tried to find a link to the manual but couldn't. It's coming directly from a removable front panel of the case that swings open like a door and has temperature, audio, and fan speed gauges. To get a better look, I'd have to take this thing all apart again. Do you think that's my best way to get a good solution? To take the front panel off and upload another picture? I will if I have to.

Comment: @paul doesn't seem to be

Comment: Search for "Apevia X-Cruiser case instructions" and check the manual for the case version you have. There appear to be 3 different versions.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's the discontinued first edition. I checked the manual and didn't see it in there. I'll have to take this thing apart again and try to take a closer look. I'll take a picture too.

Comment: Do you think I might need some type of adapter? If so, what would it be called? And, by the way, is there a better name to call the 2-pin connector in the first picture? The term "2-pin adapter" could mean almost anything.